# Cannot successfully start up command in rc.local

Tags: command-line, scripts

I want to let sslocal command automatic start up 
so I write in /etc/rc.local

```
sudo sslocal -c /etc/ss.json -d start 
plank
exit 0
```

but after I restart , `sudo systemctl status rc-local`
it shows that

```
rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d
           └─debian.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since   2017-12-07 16:05:51 +08; 6min ago
  Process: 1155 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

December 07 16:05:46 lucas-CW65S rc.local[1155]: INFO: loading config from /etc/ss.json
December 07 16:05:50 lucas-CW65S rc.local[1155]: 2017-12-07 16:05:50 INFO     loading libcrypto from libcrypto.so.1.0.0
December 07 16:05:50 lucas-CW65S sudo[1158]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
December 07 16:05:51 lucas-CW65S rc.local[1155]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: no file and directory
December 07 16:05:51 lucas-CW65S rc.local[1155]: Unable to init server: cannot connect : deny connect
December 07 16:05:51 lucas-CW65S rc.local[1155]: [WARN 16:05:51.155503] [Gtk] cannot open display:
December 07 16:05:51 lucas-CW65S systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
December 07 16:05:51 lucas-CW65S systemd[1]: Failed to start /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
December 07 16:05:51 lucas-CW65S systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Unit entered failed state.
December 07 16:05:51 lucas-CW65S systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

the key point may be `sudo[1158]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root`
and it seems that it need sudo password when switch to sudo status, but how can I input it in rc.local file ?..

Answer (score 2):

You've two problems there.

1. `/etc/rc.local` runs as root, so you don't need `sudo`
2. `rc.local` is a script, these are sequential and each command blocks execution. Run your commands in background by adding `&` at the end.

Also note that  `rc.local`  uses `#!/bin/sh -e` which means it will exit on any error. If you want the script to continue execution even if one of commands fails, use `command arg1 arg2 || true` type of approach.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple fix**: remove the word "sudo" from your script.

**Reason**: `/etc/rc.local` already runs as root, so you don't need a `sudo` there.

PS: You should not be calling `sudo` from a shell script for whatsoever reason.